# How to increase the thickness (Size) of a plane in Unity

Tags: unity, graphics

I am making a small game where you have to roll around and not fall of a platform. I am using a plane to simulate the ground, but it is really thin. Is there a way to make it thicker by increasing a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set thickness to plane because if you add thickness to plane then it will not remain a plan but it will become cube so i will suggest to use cube instead of plane.

If you need more complexity (Tries and vertices) on the cube then you have to create the cube in 3d software like maya, 3ds max, Blinder etc.